# Show that a countable union of sets of Lebesgue outer measure $0$ is a set of outer measure $0$ from the definition of $m^*$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The definition we are given is $$m^*(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n \ell(I_k) \,\middle|\, I_1, I_2, \ldots \text{ open bounded intervals, } A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n I_k\right\}$$

I get how to do it with countable subadditivity, but I don't understand how to do it directly from the definition.

For subadditivity, I think its just m*($\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$) $\leq \sum_{k=1}^n Ak = 0 + 0 + .... $ so so m*($\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$) $\leq 0$ and m*$\geq 0$ by definition so m*($\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$) = 0

Comment: That definition of $m^*$ is "Jordan outer measure", not Lebesgue. The $n$ should be replaced by $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $e>0$ let $C_{n,e}$ be a family of open intervals with $\cup C_{n,e}\supset A_n$ and $\sum_{J\in C_{n,e}}l(J)\leq e2^{-n}.$ For brevity let $D=\{C_{n,e}: n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Then $\cup_{n\in \Bbb n}A_n\subset \cup D$ so $$m^*(\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}A_n)\leq \sum_{J\in \cup D}l(J)\leq \sum_{n\in \Bbb N}\sum_{J\in C_{n,e}}l(J)\leq \sum_{n\in \Bbb N}e2^{-n}=e.$$ So $m^*(\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}A_n)\leq e$ for any $e>0.$